# How to expand a NavigationView to full screen from a TabView with fixed dimensions?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `VStack` which combines two views. One is a regular `Rectangle` and the other is a `TabView` that rotates through other rectangles. One of the rectangles acts like a button into a `NavigationView` which renders a calendar to a user.

In my current code the calendar stays the same size as the `TabView` but I want the calendar to expand to the full screen (removing the green rectangle and going to a completely different view). How can one achieve this?

Current code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 250)
            TabView {
                Rectangle()
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                Rectangle()
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationLink(destination: CalendarView()) {
                        Text("Tap for calendar.")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: PageIndexViewStyle.BackgroundDisplayMode.always))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to wrap the entire thing in a `NavigationView`...

```swift
mport SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 250)
            TabView {
                Rectangle()
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                Rectangle()
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationLink(destination: CalendarView()) {
                        Text("Tap for calendar.")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: PageIndexViewStyle.BackgroundDisplayMode.always))
        }
    }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```